# export android project add facebook sdk get error convert to dalvik format failed with error 1

Tags: facebook, sdk, export

i am doing a small project on android and it using facebook sdk 3.0. everything is ok until i export to upload android market, i got error "error convert to dalvik format failed with error 1" and i try export 2 sample projects in sdk, i got same error. i research on google ,the cause is the projects and facebook sdk have same name file R.java in com.facebook.android. But  because it file R.java so i cannot rename it. i try other way, i turn off "build automatically" and delete R.java file in facebook sdk, it can export keystore and apk file but apk file don not work. So what can i do to fix it?

thanks

Comment: What I do is: "Clean & rebuild all used project", "[UnChecked] all used project/library in my APP's properties-JavaBuildPath-OrderandExport", "[Checked again] all used project/library in my APP's properties-JavaBuildPath-OrderandExport"......sounds stupid but works......

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem too with an app that used Facebook SDK. I was trying all sorts of stuff, so I'm not sure what exactly fixed but here's settings that worked for me:

FacebookSDK > Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export

Android 2.2 - NOT CHECKED

Android Private Libraries - CHECKED

Android Dependencies - CHECKED

MyApp > Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export

Android 4.2.2 - CHECKED

Android Private Libraries - CHECKED

Android Dependencies - CHECKED

In addition, I had done this before, not sure it mattered. Reverted to Facebook SDK version 3.5 from 3.5.2. Updated to latest ADT 22.2.1. Changed Facebook SDK to use Android 2.2 from 4.2.2.